# How to calculate cumulative sum and average on file data in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a below data in file

```
NAME,AGE,MARKS
A1,12,40
B1,13,54
C1,15,67
D1,11,41
E1,16,59
F1,10,60
```

If the data was in database table , I would have used `Sum` and `Average` function to get the cumulative sum and average

But How to get it with python is a bit challenging , As i am learner

**Expected output :**

```
 NAME,AGE,MARKS,CUM_SUM,AVG
    A1,12,40,40,40
    B1,13,54,94,47
    C1,15,67,161,53.66
    D1,11,41,202,50.5
    E1,16,59,261,43.5
    F1,10,60,321,45.85
```

Comment: Is this a csv file or some different format? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file')


df['CUM_SUM'] = df['MARKS'].cumsum()

df['AVG'] = df['MARKS'].expanding().mean()
print (df)
  NAME  AGE  MARKS  CUM_SUM        AVG
0   A1   12     40       40  40.000000
1   B1   13     54       94  47.000000
2   C1   15     67      161  53.666667
3   D1   11     41      202  50.500000
4   E1   16     59      261  52.200000
5   F1   10     60      321  53.500000
```

Last use:

```
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

Or:

```
out = df.to_string(index=False)
```

Comment: can you print output in comma separated format

Comment: can you show how you read data from file `df` from where it came